# Could not find the file after uploading

Tags: c#

I am working on website where you can merge multiple PDF files into one file,

but the problem I am facing is every time I try uploading the file I get this error:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express
```

and I have upload the files from this path (C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express) to make it work.

my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload");
    HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
    Span1.Text = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

        if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));

            Span1.Text += "Location where saved: " + filepath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";

        }
        }
```

Comment: Try using relative path here: `Server.MapPath("\\Upload")` => `Server.MapPath("~/Upload")`

Comment: thanks for the replay but I am getting the same error

Comment: Pls send code block

Comment: Hüseyin BurakKaradag I added the code in the question above